# After MySQL Query, row shows blank values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update some values in a database and after executing a query it will not update the values in the database, only replace it with a blank value.

This is my php code:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $tbl_name . ' SET `Name` = \'' . $name .'\', `Store` = \'apples\', `URL` = \'apples\', `SKU` = \'apples\', `Price` = \'apples\', `Location` = \'apples\' WHERE CONVERT(`crisss1205_me_com`.`ID` USING utf8) = \'1\' LIMIT 1;';
```

and it doesn't return any errors. The variable **$name** is coming from a $_POST

If I print out the query using `echo $sql;` it looks like this:

> UPDATE crisss1205_me_com SET `Name` = 'HelloWorld', `Store` = 'apples', `URL` = 'apples', `SKU` = 'apples', `Price` = 'apples', `Location` = 'apples' WHERE CONVERT(`crisss1205_me_com`.`ID` USING utf8) = '1' LIMIT 1;

But in the database under the "Name" column it shows a blank space.

If I leave the query alone but change `$name = $_POST['name'];` to `$name = "HelloWorld";` it will update the database fine.

What could be the reason why it will not show up from a "POST"?

---

```
 <?php

$tbl_name = $_COOKIE['e-mail_ctt'];
require_once('../config.php');

    $name = (string)$_POST['name'];
    $store = $_POST['store'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $sku = $_POST['sku'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $demo = "app";

$sql = "UPDATE " . $tbl_name . " SET Name='" . $name . "', Store='" . $store . "', URL='" . $url . "', SKU='" . $sku . "', Price='" . $price . "', Location='" . $location . $demo . "' WHERE ID='1';";
echo $sql;
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

exit ;

?>
```

Browser Source code:

```
UPDATE crisss1205_me_com SET Name='Mac', Store='mac', URL='mac', SKU='mac', Price='mac', Location='Online Store Onlyapp' WHERE ID='1';
```

Database:

[image]

Comment: is that echoed sql the exact copy/pasted output? it seems to be missing the ` characters. something weird is going on here.

Comment: That is a bit strange that the \` characters don't show up. Good catch @dqhendricks. @Christan, is that string being echoed after mysql or mysqli has had its way with it? or immediately after the `$sql = `... line?

Comment: That is the exact copy from my browser.

Comment: Yeah, but where is the `echo $sql;` in the flow of the code?

Comment: Well, then 1) check your HTML and make sure that `<input name="name"`...`>` is in there correctly and not misspelled, and then 2) you need to figure out what is eating the \` characters off of your string.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. Check the HTML.

Comment: The \` characters are not strictly necessary on a "normally" configured MySQL server, so they are not critical, but if they aren't making it into the string, I worry about your PHP installation or some other weirdness.

Comment: @RobertB It's not the HTML because I can print out the variables and they are fine. If I do a "INSERT INTO" instead of "UPDATE" it works fine. I have no idea why its eating up the ` in the string. This is just the weirdest thing I have ever seen. Its not even my server, I thing this server is a GoDaddy hosting server.

Comment: I'm in the PHP chatroom if you want. You say that you can print out the variables, so `$name = $_POST['name']; echo $name;` gives you "Christian" or whatever you typed and submitted?

Comment: Ok, so the backticks _are_ there. The planet is not off its axis. Just the missing $name value then.

Comment: "$name = $_POST['name']; echo $name; gives you "Christian" or whatever you typed and submitted? " Yes

Comment: Stumped. If it is spelled correctly and not disabled in the html form, and has a proper value after `$name = $_POST['name'];`, then I'm not seeing what's preventing ...`' SET \`Name\` = \'' . $name .'\'`... from giving you what you'd expect.

Comment: :-P The \` in the first paste disappeared because of markdown.

Comment: Obligatory plug: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/security.database.php

Comment: Rewrote the query and it added some more debugging code, still puzzles me. Check above for edited version again.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your `name` attribute on the posted field in your form is simply misspelled. Dump out the `$_POST` contents to see if it contains what you expect, and double-check the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem when using the POST method. If I change the form to use GET and then change the PHP to use $_GET or $_REQUEST it works fine. I would like to use POST but I am using AJAX to send the form details and security is not an issue. I will have to GET as a workaround for now until I find out what the heck is going on.